# Get terminal status for termcap capabilities

Tags: scripting, terminal, terminfo, tput

How can one retrieve status of terminal settings like `smam` and `rmam` ?

Reason is that I set `rmam` by:

```
tput rmam
```

in script, then proceed to set `smam` on exit:

```
tput smam
```

But if terminal has `rmam` set when script starts, I do not want to set `smam` on exit.

---

How can this be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On terminal emulators which support it, you can use the `\033[?7$p` escape ("Request DEC private mode") to query that parameter (`7` => Auto-wrap Mode):

```bash
decrqm()(
    exec </dev/tty
    t=$(stty -g)
    trap 'stty "$t"; return' EXIT QUIT INT TERM
    stty -icanon -echo time 1 min 0
    e=$(printf '\033')
    printf "${e}[$1\$p" >/dev/tty
    case $(dd count=1 2>/dev/null) in
    "${e}[$1;1\$y") echo on;;
    "${e}[$1;2\$y") echo off;;
    *) echo unknown;;
    esac
)

$ tput smam  # printf '\033[?7h'
$ decrqm '?7'
on
$ tput rmam  # printf '\033[?7l'
$ decrqm '?7'
off
```

A better approach would be to *save* that setting upon starting the script with `\033[?7s` and *restore* it upon exiting with `\033[?7r`:

```bash
save_am(){ printf '\033[?7s'; }
restore_am(){ printf '\033[?7r'; }

save_am
tput rmam
..
restore_am
```

---

But many terminal emulators (notably `screen` and `tmux`) **do not support** those escapes. At least not by default. So all this is pure trivia -- it's not like you can use it for anything practical ;-)

Comment: Thank you! It is unlikely anyone have a better way, but I'll wait a little before accepting. The screen / tmux issue is a big drawback ;)

Answer (score 0):

Extremely ugly but a hack to detect:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Detect smam / rmam by printing COLUMNS characters and 
# checking cursor line before and after.

smam()
(
    local -i smam r1 r2 cw
    exec </dev/tty
    local t=$(stty -g)
    trap 'stty "$t"; return' EXIT QUIT INT TERM
    stty -icanon -echo time 1 min 0

    # Terminal width + 1
    (( cw = $(tput cols) + 1 ))

    # Create a blank line and go back up (in case we are at bottom)
    printf "\n"
    tput cuu1
    # Get cursor row 1
    printf "\x1b[6n" >/dev/tty
    r1=$(dd count=1 2>/dev/null | sed 's/\x1b\[\(.*\);.*/\1/')
    # Print columns + 1 spaces
    for ((i = 0; i < cw; ++i)); do printf " "; done
    # Get cursor row 2 AND go to start of line
    printf "\x1b[6n\r" >/dev/tty
    r2=$(dd count=1 2>/dev/null | sed 's/\x1b\[\(.*\);.*/\1/')

    # smam is true if we are at a higher line number
    (( smam = r2 - r1 ))
    # Clear line
    tput el
    # If smam clear line we started on as well
    (( smam )) && tput cuu1 && tput el
    # Optional debug check 
    # printf "%d %d\n" $x1 $x2
    return $(( smam ^ 1 ))
)

# example:

smam && echo smam || echo rmam
```

One quirk is that one have to be on a new line on call.